# Insert clicks counter in p5

Tags: numbers, counter, p5.js

I'm new and I start using coding for a university project using p5.js
I would like to know how to insert in my pag a click counter, in which text numbers change when mouse is clicked. 
I hope someone could help me, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//defining a variable to store the number of clicks
var clicks = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background(50);
  //text formatting
  noStroke();
  fill(255);
  textSize(80);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  //displaying number of clicks
  text(clicks, width/2, height/2);
}

//function is called when user clicks
function mousePressed() {
  //add 1 to variable clicks
  clicks ++;
}
```

Comment: OMG so usefull!! It's exactly the code I need! Thank you so much Pepe!! :D

Comment: @AlicePaganini If this answer was helpful you should consider marking it as accepted by clicking the tick on the left hand side of this answer, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for more specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. So you should really **try something** and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when you get stuck. Recommended reading: [How to Program](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program).

That being said, I can try to help in a general sense:

**Step 1:** You need to store the number of clicks in a variable.

**Step 2:** Increment that variable whenever the user clicks.

**Step 3:** Use that variable to display the clicks. Start out by just printing it to the console, then display it using the `text()` function, and then go from there if you want to do something more complicated.

If you're stuck on a specific step, then please post an MCVE showing exactly what you tried (in a new question post), and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for my general question and thank u for yours advices, i will read How to program! Thank you :)

Comment: "By downvoting a correct answer, you're making it more difficult for the OP to get help. And if you aren't on this site to help people, why are you here?"

Comment: @Pepe Some would argue that spoonfeeding code (which is the easy part of programming) isn't really helping. If you really want to help, you should help the user through **the process** of splitting a problem up and approaching one small piece at a time. Anybody can regurgitate code. If you really want to help somebody, help them through the process.

Comment: @KevinWorkman She asked for some code, i gave it to her "OMG so usefull!! It's exactly the code I need! Thank you so much Pepe!! :D" why would you downvote my answer if that is what the OP asked for?

Comment: @Pepe Programming is more than just regurgitating code. It's working through **the process** of problem solving and breaking things down. You just did somebody's code for them, which at best robs them of the process of actually learning anything, and at worst could get them kicked out of school for violating academic honesty policies. Think about it this way: if somebody said they were having trouble solving a math problem, would you just do their homework for them? Or would you walk them through the process of solving it themselves?

Comment: @Pepe I believe that you're trying to help. But trying to help doesn't always mean regurgitating code.